# Counting cards, with a tree

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I propose the following problem.

> Suppose you and I are playing a game of cards in which a winner is decided upon the cards we draw. This game of cards consist of colored cards:
>
> Yellow, red, orange, blue, green, purple, but **four** of the yellow cards and **one** of the orange cards are marked with an $X$ on it.
>
> A winner is decided when **four** yellow cards with $X$ and **one** orange card with $X$ is in the player's hand. Both players start with no cards in the beginning.
>
> One rule in this game is that if you get a yellow card (with $X$ on it or not), you are allowed to draw $2$ more cards for each yellow card.
>
> **For example**: On the first draw, I get a yellow card. This means I can draw $2$ more cards making a total of $3$ cards in my hand. However, if any of the $2$ cards I have drawn are also yellow, then I draw 2 more for each card.

I have modelled this using a tree diagram. This is a very bad pictorial tree made from PhotoShop. As soon as I reached the $2$nd level of the tree, it got very messy and I had to stop because I simply got lost on the left side with the three straight $Y$.

> **Legend**: $Y$ = yellow card; $C$ = other cards
> [image]

The red circles indicate that I have noticed a recurring subtree. I have very little background in graph theory, so I am not sure if this has been solved already.

My question: Is there a formula (a sequence perhaps?) that models the number of cards I have to draw for each yellow card I get? The order of the sequence do matter as you can see from the tree.

I hope to extend this problem when the rules are changed to drawing **three** cards for each yellow card

Comment: Howmany cards of each colour  are there in total?

Comment: I see what you are asking. You are asking if the tree will terminate. Let us separate the cases when the deck is infinite and finite. I want to see a solution for a deck of infinite size first.